# else not being activated in my code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner and I have written the following code. My problem is that I am not being able to stop the while loop by setting "continuar" to False. My idea is that when the input is not 1 nor 2, the last else should do that, but it does not. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

```
import random
print("Vamos a usar la estrategia de la martingala")
print("La apuesta mínima es 1€")
dinero_inicial=int(input("Con cuanto dinero empiezas? "))
dinero=dinero_inicial
dinero_apostado=1
continuar=True
while dinero>=dinero_apostado and continuar==True:
    print()
    apuesta=int(input("Introduce 1 para el negro, 2 para el rojo o otro número para retirarte: "))
    if apuesta==1 or apuesta==2:
        casilla=random.choices([0,1,2],[1,18,18])
        casilla=casilla.pop()
        if casilla==0:
            print("Ha salido el 0")
        elif casilla==1:
            print("Ha salido el negro")
        elif casilla==2:
            print("Ha salido el rojo")
        if casilla==apuesta:
            print("Felicidades, has ganado la apuesta")
            dinero=dinero+dinero_apostado
            dinero_apostado=1
        elif casilla != apuesta:
            print("Has perdido la apuesta")
            dinero=dinero-dinero_apostado
            dinero_apostado=dinero_apostado*2
        print("Te quedan {}€ y ahora apostarás {}€ ".format(dinero,dinero_apostado))
    else:
        continuar==False
print()
print("Has dejado de jugar")
if dinero>dinero_inicial:
    print("Has acabado con {}€ y has ganado {}€".format(dinero,dinero-dinero-dinero_inicial))
else:
    print("Has acabado con {}€ y has perdido {}€".format(dinero,dinero_inicial-dinero))
```

Comment: You wrote `continuar==False`, which compares `continuar` to False; you probably meant `continuar = False`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you aren't actually setting it to False in your else. You are doing an equality check of the variable continuar against False:

== Checks equality:

```
continuar==False
```

= Sets the value:

```
continuar=False
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to write `continuar = False` which assigns the variable continuar the value False, but `continuar == False` checks if the variable continuar is False which results in False because it is True.